# jqGrid id undefined, why?

Tags: jqgrid

I have this code:

```
$(grid).jqGrid('addRowData', 'foo', d);
$(grid).jqGrid('addRowData', 'bar', 'baz');
```

As viewed in FireBug, it creates this DOM:

```
<tr id="undefined" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" role="row">
<tr id="bar" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" role="row">
```

The data expressed in 'd' matches the column model and it displays correctly (so I know the grid basically works fine). BUT, the 'id' on the first row is not set. On the other hand, 'baz' is garbage; this creates a blank row, BUT, the 'id' is correctly set to 'bar'.

In both cases I am sure the ID's are unique within my DOM, plus, I have observed that using non-unique ID's does not cause any immediate problems.

SO; I can't see why the id on the first row is not set. Any ideas?

Comment: please post the data that is in "d" I assume this is just one row of data and the JSON may be malformed with only one item in the data object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788197/jqgrid-not-displaying-a-single-row

Comment: Aha, when I went to do this, I noticed that the JSON indeed (and inadvertently) contained an unnecessary 1-element array (around the single data item). It's curious that the grid rendered OK, but then choked on assigning the ID. But clearly my error .Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
   $(grid).jqGrid('addRowData', 'foo', 'd');
   $(grid).jqGrid('addRowData', 'bar', 'baz');
```

data should be in quote otherwise you can declare the variable

like

```
  var d='sample';
  $(grid).jqGrid('addRowData', 'foo', d);
  $(grid).jqGrid('addRowData', 'bar', 'baz');
```

Suppose d is an array check d and d[0] if d[0] have a value then go with d[0] :-

```
  $(grid).jqGrid('addRowData', 'foo', d[0]);
             (or)
  $(grid).jqGrid('addRowData', 'foo', d[id]);
```

it will be work fine...