# Jqgrid not displaying single row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

The below given string is not getting displayed on my jqgrid

```
    {"assignfix":{"sno":"1","fix":"Se2","templateName":"Restroom","profile":{"id":"11","name":"Restroom"}}}
```

But when I insert this

```
 {"assignfix":[{"sno":"1","fix":"Sef2","templateName":"Restroom","profile":{"id":"11","name":"Restroom"}}]}
```

It gets displayed properly , it is the problem with single row only.

Comment: Also the xml returned from the server and json are different...it is missing with the parent tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't posted the definition of jqGrid which you use where the `jsonReader` or `xmlReader` are important to know. In general I think you answered yourself indirectly on your question. If the value of `assignfix` property should be **array** you should post the data as an array event if the array has one element or if it has no elements. It should be still array.

Comment: Thanks.But I got the point where this is the bug in jqgrid , it cannot add the single row of jsonstring, so you have to add manually.

Comment: @user1671219: You are welcome! If you use `{"assignfix":[{...}]}` syntax to add one row of data all should work correctly. If you do have an example which don't work you should post the full example which reproduces the problem.